# I can only access the internet through TOR

Tags: censorship

Something really weird has been happening, I've trying to access a bunch of sites like

> stackexchange.com
>
> twitter.com
>
> **google.com**
>
> **reddit.com**

and a lot more through my normal connection with chrome/firefox but none of them are working, I literally can't access the internet at all.

Ping requests on the terminal are not resolved either.

The only way I can access the internet is by using the tor browser. My question is, **does this mean I'm being censored somehow?**

Comment: Can you ping IP addresses rather than domain names? For example does "ping 8.8.8.8" work? What about "ping google.com"? It might just be a problem with your domain resolution. Have you made any changes to your networking configuration? (There are all sorts of blogs online that tell you to make weird and unhelpful changes to your network settings in order to improve your anonymity.)

Comment: @Steve ping 8.8.8.8 works, ping google.com doesn't. I haven't changed anything, actually I don't even have access to the router

Comment: @Steve I tried pinging the IP of the websites I listed, it seems to work but my browser still won't access them, even if I manually insert the IP

Comment: Are you on Linux (or do you have access to the WSL)? If so, try running `dig google.com` (there is probably an equivalent tool for Windows). How about `dig google.com @208.67.222.222` (the OpenDNS resolver IP). It is probably a problem with your DNS server, so I would try finding the DNS settings for your OS/browser and change it to one like the OpenDNS resolver `208.67.222.222`.

Comment: @Steve thanks Steve,I don't what happened, everything was working yesterday... Anyway changing to OpenDNS did the job

Comment: No problem, it might be a problem with your router or another upstream DNS server. You can try changing it back in a few days and maybe it will be fixed. There's also a possibility that your DNS server was blocked by a censor, but I would have expected OpenDNS to be blocked too in that case. The reason it worked on Tor is that the exit relay does the DNS lookup for you, rather than using your local DNS server.